# Promise only resolves correctly on page refresh

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I am playing around with an API that gets a list of Pokemon and corresponding data that looks like this.

```
export function SomePage() {
const [arr, setArray] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
    fetchSomePokemon();
  }, []);


  function fetchSomePokemon() {
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=5')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then((pokemonList) => {
       const someArray = [];
     pokemonList.results.map(async (pokemon: { url: string; }) => {
       someArray.push(await fetchData(pokemon))
     })
     setArray([...arr, someArray]);
    })
   }

   async function fetchData(pokemon: { url: string; }) {
    let url = pokemon.url
     return await fetch(url).then(async res => await res.json())
    }

    console.log(arr);

  return (
      <div>
      {arr[0]?.map((pokemon, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
          >
            {pokemon.name}
          </div>
        ))
      }
      </div>
  );
}
```

The code works(kind of) however on the first render the map will display nothing even though the console.log outputs data. Only once the page has been refreshed will the correct data display. I have a feeling it's something to do with not handling promises correctly. Perhaps someone could help me out.
TIA

Expected output: Data populated on initial render(in this case, pokemon names will display)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The in-build `map` method on arrays in synchronous in nature. In `fetchSomePokemon` you need to return a promise from map callback function since you're writing async code in it.

Now items in array returned by `pokemonList.results.map` are promises. You need to use `Promise.all` on `pokemonList.results.map` and `await` it.

```js
await Promise.all(pokemonList.results.map(async (pokemon: { url: string; }) => {
       return fetchData.then(someArray.push(pokemon))
     }));
```

Comment: I can confirm that this fixed it after making the subfunction pokemonList async as well.

Comment: I'd suggest `const dataFetchers = pokemonList.results.map(fetchData); const someArray = await Promise.all(dataFetchers);`

Comment: @mbdavis Yes! That'd be better. I wanted to make minimal changes on the code in question

Comment: Ah yes of course - this was directed at @PengProgrammer :)

Comment: @mbdavis. Yes definitely, this is much cleaner implementation! Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

On your first render, you don't have the data yet, so `arr[0]` doens't exist for you to `.map` on it, so it crashes. You need to check if the data is already there before mapping.

Using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), if there's no data it will not throw an error on your first render and it will render correctly when the data arrive and it re-renders.

```
...
  return (
    <div>
      {arr[0]?.map((pokemon, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{pokemon.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey @Glauco. I have tried this prior to posting also with no success. I will update the code though, so that these possibilities are represented :) Thanks

Comment: @PengProgrammer I just created a test page here with your code and using optional chaining and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

in

`useEffect(() => { fetchSomePokemon(); }, []);`

`[]` tells react there is no dependencies for this effect to happen,

read more here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: Hey @Madhu. yeah I know there are not deps added in this case, but even if you add deps, it still doesnt work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your issues is to `await` the data fetching in `useEffect()`.

Here's a POC:

```js
export function Page() {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);

  // will fetch the pokemon on the first render
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPokemon() {
      // ... logic that fetches the pokemon
    }
    
    fetchPokemon();
  }, []);

  if (!pokemon.length) {
    // you can return a spinner here
    return null;
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {pokemon.map(item => {
        // return an element
      })}
    </div>
  );
 }
```